# Heroku console doesn't handle ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Simple question - I'm trying to assign random values to some of my app's fields on Heroku by writing:

```
Project.all.each do |p|; p.key ||= ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex; p.save; end
```

This is producing the `internal server error` due to the hex.

Do you know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

#### Edit: It turns out the failure was due to an hour-long Heroku outage that killed tools as well as slowing down apps. hex still works on Heroku console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the failure was due to an hour-long Heroku outage that killed tools as well as slowing down apps. hex still works on Heroku console.

Thanks leonardoborges and Skydreamer for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try just running the line `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex` on Heroku's console?

I just did that and it worked, so the error might be elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `heroku logs` in your project to see exactly what's wrong and fix it.